# log4net doesn't write log entries until application close

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I want log4net to write to my ADO log immediately but it doesn't seem to do it until the application exists, how can I remedy this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to configure the buffer size like this:

```
<bufferSize value="1" />
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to configure my appender by adding a parameter to it as follows:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  [...]
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  [...]
</appender>
```

I just set the locking model to minimal lock, and that did the job.

HTH

Comment: This is what solved it for me, thanks!